# Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for date column

Tags: mysql, sql-mode

I'm trying to run the following script in MySQL Workbench:

```
UPDATE `people` SET `dateDied` = '0000-00-00';
```

And I get this error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect date value: '0000-00-00' for column 'dateDied' at row 1
```

Now I have already disabled strict mode in the `my.ini` that MySQL Workbench is set to use

```
sql_mode = ""
```

I did a scan for any `my.ini` in my drive where MySQL is installed and that is the only one I see that exists. I have a Laravel application running with strict mode off just fine but for whatever reason MySQL Workbench is giving me that error and I don't know why. It's almost like its ignoring that value. I have restarted MySQL and MySQL Workbench several times but cannot get that script to run successfully.

What am I missing?

Comment: You should have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36374335/error-in-mysql-when-setting-default-value-for-date-or-datetime/36374690#36374690

Comment: You're trying to set the system-wide value. Assuming you succeed (not sure if you verify that) the application can still set a different session value and override server's default.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [1292: Incorrect datetime value: '' for column 'TERM\_DATE' at row 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28530195/1292-incorrect-datetime-value-for-column-term-date-at-row-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running MySQL Workbench as Administrator and running this query resolved it for me:

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = '';
```

For some reason updating the my.ini with the following did not take care of it.

```
sql_mode = ''
```